# How do I create a new column that counts specific values in rows of another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

My dataframe in R which has ID and value:

```r
ID = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1)
Value= c("\N","1","2","3","5","6","7","\N","1","2")

df = data.frame(ID, Value)
```

I want to create three new columns, one called podium, one called finished and one called lost.
I want podium to count for each ID, if the Value was either 1,2 or 3.
I want lost to count for each ID, if the value was "\N"
and the remaining to get counted in finished.

Basically  I want the output to look like this:

```r
ID = c(1,2,3)
Podium = c(2,1,2)
Finished = c(1,1,1)
Lost=c(1,1,0)

df = data.frame(ID, Podium, Finished, Lost)
```

Comment: Does the provided code run on your machine? The `Value = ...` line produces an error `"Error: '\N' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\N"` using R 4.0.3

Comment: Yes I added an extra "\"

Answer (score 1):

This is doable, but first, a word of warning about your use of "\N". Backslashes in character strings denote [escaped characters](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html), and because "\N" isn't a recognised code for an escaped character, R throws the following error when I try to reproduce your dataframe `df`:

```
Error: '\N' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\N"
```

To get around this, I removed the backslashes in your example. I suggest you also recode this part of your data, so that you don't run into problems caused by escaped characters later on in your analysis.

That being done, your problem itself has an easy solution using functions from the `{tidyverse}` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Your original data
df = data.frame(
    ID = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1), 
    Value = c("N","1","2","3","5","6","7","N","1","2")
)

result <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Value = as.character(Value)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    Podium = sum(Value <= 3),
    Finished = sum(Value != "N" & Value > 3),
    Lost = sum(Value == "N")
  )
```

With this, your result looks like:

```
    ID Podium Finished  Lost
  <dbl>  <int>    <int> <int>
     1      2        1     1
     2      1        1     1
     3      2        1     0
```

Comment: This is great, however I just realised that my numbers are strings so i am unable to do Value <= 3. Is it possible to put an or statement?

Comment: @user12204086 If you define your data as a tibble before summarising, then the sum statements should still work. I've edited my answer to include this change, assuming you're starting with a data.frame as in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = case_when(
    Value %in% 1:3 ~ "Podium",
    Value == "N" ~ "Lost",
    TRUE ~ "Finished"
  )) %>%
  count(ID, Value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Value, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

Here I convert the Value to the provided categories using `dplyr::case_when`, then count the combinations using `dplyr::count`, and then pivot the result to wider format using `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Give some context to your answer and add the librarys you used.